# Is there any way to write a listBuffer to HDFS in CSV format using Scala/Java?

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, hdfs, export-to-csv

I am having a listBuffer with some records. I need to write it into HDFS in CSV format.

Comment: Sure, it's possible. For example, parallelize the data with Spark then write it. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Thank you for your response @OneCricketeer . I'm trying it to do without spark. I think I got the solution. Once the results are verified, I will be posting it

Comment: Sure, you can write to a file locally, then use Filesystem class from Hadoop to upload. That's really all Spark is doing (although you can't control the file name, and it  splits the data into partitions)